# Struggling to get Eclipse Groovy Batch compiler running in IntelliJ 2016.2.4

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, groovy-eclipse

I'd like to compile Groovy in IntelliJ IDEA using the Eclipse groovy batch compiler.  But I'm struggling to find solid documentation of how to get this to work, or what to expect.

Naively I've downloaded the latest batch compiler from Maven Central:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3-01</version>
    </dependency>
```

I've then set the java compiler in the IDEA settings to use it:

```
Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler
    Use Compiler: Groovy-Eclipse
Path to groovy-eclipse-batch jar:
    /tmp/groovy-eclipse-batch-2.4.3-01.jar
```

When I ask IDEA to compile the groovy files in my project (which were previously being compiled using the groovy compiler) it just returns this error for each file:

```
Error:(1, -1) Groovy-Eclipse: Groovy:Internal groovy compiler error.
```

I can't find anything significant in any of the IDEA log files.

Does anyone have a working IDEA/groovy-eclipse-batch environment? Are there any gotchas that I'm missing?

Comment: Please file an issue to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com and provide `log/idea.log` and `log/build-log folder` contents there.

Comment: Thanks @PeterGromov, I've done that: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-177620

Answer (score 0):

There are newer Groovy-Eclipse compiler artifacts available through bintray.  They contain a lot of bug fixes and compatibility for Java 9, Config Scripts, InvokeDynamic and more.

https://bintray.com/groovy/maven/groovy-eclipse-batch